# Facebook SDK integration with Android Studio

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity, android-studio, android-facebook

I am trying to integrate Facebook SDK into my android project but unable to do so. I have followed the steps mentioned in the facebook documentation. but I am getting the error as -

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/dx --dex --num-threads=4 --output /Volumes/Data/projects/project_name/build/intermediates/dex/debug /Volumes/Data/projects/project_name/build/intermediates/classes/debug /Volumes/Data/projects/project_name/build/intermediates/dependency-cache/debug /Volumes/Data/projects/project_name/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/bolts-57446fde6c024f562e020fd9e003407a5fc2a578.jar /Volumes/Data/projects/project_name/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/bugsense-3.5-8ab33d75af263f7f86f49230e10099a1c2c9a549.jar /Volumes/Data/projects/project_name/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-0523eab2b91bd947bf3140cde551a15ef204bab4.jar /Volumes/Data/projects/project_name/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-1bf58233e09b0ba3df3b170e5976ea8835ce9dbc.jar /Volumes/Data/projects/project_name/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-50cb56f46834855caa39a5bee8fee3da46d5c1eb.jar /Volumes/Data/projects/project_name/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-5656b1a26fb9cf46c5e761b517ec752c47e7afe7.jar /Volumes/Data/projects/project_name/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-d98d71fc376b8658355216fd82eb5433791f3b1d.jar /Volumes/Data/projects/project_name/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/custom-linkedin-j-android-46399e5197dc53ee00e0370db8440536b745b26a.jar /Volumes/Data/projects/project_name/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/droidText.0.5-809fa4af200fcd621ea1d4d33c187c85ccfb4721.jar /Volumes/Data/projects/project_name/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/gson-2.2.4-1f9beaae96795dd030e7971a8a89b53987904e64.jar /Volumes/Data/projects/project_name/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/libGoogleAnalyticsServices-969197b4a3de6e6538e72f3e6d598b94488ccd57.jar /Volumes/Data/projects/project_name/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/Parse-1.5.0-e86e2456aff7f83bdad45e275836d6a3e12c84c9.jar /Volumes/Data/projects/project_name/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1-ad7399087713b6c6e45b1e45950da833fcc81870.jar /Volumes/Data/projects/project_name/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/signpost-core-1.2.1.1-50384ca3c3962abba499d71f329139d20bac4475.jar /Volumes/Data/projects/project_name/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1-96a3b59a9846e0434e4213c2f1c063549d7f2b83.jar /Volumes/Data/projects/project_name/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/support-v4-19.0.1-3bf117e59e2e0f41bbf9219f2be90cdcf1dd583d.jar
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:

    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Cannot merge new index 67781 into a non-jumbo instruction!
        at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.jumboCheck(InstructionTransformer.java:108)
        at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.access$800(InstructionTransformer.java:25)
        at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer$StringVisitor.visit(InstructionTransformer.java:71)
        at com.android.dx.io.CodeReader.callVisit(CodeReader.java:114)
        at com.android.dx.io.CodeReader.visitAll(CodeReader.java:89)
        at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.transform(InstructionTransformer.java:48)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformCode(DexMerger.java:840)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformMethods(DexMerger.java:811)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformClassData(DexMerger.java:783)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformClassDef(DexMerger.java:680)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:540)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

This is my Facebook gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
    compile files('libs/bolts.jar')
}
```

and this is my project gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':libraries:actionbarsherlock')
    compile project(':libraries:sliding-menu')
    compile project(':libraries:cwac-touchlist')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.5.0.jar')
    compile 'com.bugsense.trace:bugsense:3.5'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile project(':facebook')
}
```

Any suggestions on this ? Please let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the same JAR is being imported again. Suppose, there was a class inside a jar which was getting imported in another jar. So just check if the any lib / class file is being included twice.

**OR**
If your just import some jar files, you could try to remove them, and add one at a time, to see which one of them makes the error.
In my case, i did just that, and when i was importing the last one, the app did compile. So i think, that i perhaps imported to many at a time, and that was the real problem. But now it all works.

Answer (score 1):

Android applications have a build step where the dex tool takes your Java class files and converts them to a format that Android devices can run directly. There are limitations in the output file format, one of which is a limit in the number of strings the file can contain unless an option is set to turn on "jumbo mode". You can set the flag to turn on jumbo mode, which may help you with this error, but be aware that you may be nearing other limits as well (in particular, there's a limit to the total number of methods that can be in your application, unless you split it up into multiple dex files). If you see future errors, do some research along those lines.

In any event, to enable jumbo mode, try putting this in the `android` block of the **build.gradle** file of the module that's having the error:

```
dexOptions {
    jumboMode = true
}
```